# RabbitMQ Pika - how to check if a consumer is active

Tags: rabbitmq, pika

Does anyone know what is the easiest way to check if a consumer is active for a particular queue? I could hit the api on localhost manually, but I'd love a way to do this with Pika.

For example, I have a queue `xyz` I want to know how many consumers are listening to that queue.

Answer (score 2):

You can do a `queue.declare` with `passive=true` for the same queue you want to get the consumer count from. This will return a response [(`queue.declare-ok`) which includes the consumer count](https://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html#queue.declare-ok).

From [the protocol reference documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html#queue.declare.passive):

> bit **passive**
>
> If set, the server will reply with Declare-Ok if the queue already
>   exists with the same name, and raise an error if not. The client can
>   use this to check whether a queue exists without modifying the server
>   state.